# Migraciones no restringen el ingreso de llaves foráneas no existentes

Tags: mysql, laravel

Estaba haciendo mis migraciones de las tablas MUNDO y RAZA. `(*1 Mundo x N Raza*)`, quise probar si las restricciones de las llaves foráneas estaban funcionando.

Entonces inserte un **mundo** :

```
id:1
nombre:DyD
descripcion:lorem...
```

Ahora pase a insertar una **raza**, la cual pertence a un **mundo**:

```
id:1
nombre:orco
descripcion:lorem...
mundo_id:3
```

Se puede observar **que estoy insertando un ID mundo que no existe**. Pues bien, la BD se lo traga con papas y no me lo impide con un mensaje como: *estas intentando referenciar un mundo que no existe*. Las migraciones son las siguientes:

**Migracion mundo**

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;
use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;

class CreateMundosTable extends Migration
{
    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('mundos', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->bigIncrements('id');
            $table->string('nombre')->unique();
            $table->string('descripcion');
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }

    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function down()
    {
        Schema::dropIfExists('mundos');
    }
}
```

**Migracion raza**

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;
use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;

class CreateRazasTable extends Migration
{
    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('razas', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->bigIncrements('id');
            $table->string('nombre')->unique();
            $table->string('descripcion');
            $table->timestamps();

            $table->unsignedBigInteger('mundo_id');

            $table->foreign('mundo_id')->references('id')->on('mundos');

        });

    }

    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function down()
    {
        Schema::dropIfExists('razas');
    }
}
```

Decir que he creado las *foraneas* como lo indica la [documentacion de Laravel - Foreign Key Constraints](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/migrations#foreign-key-constraints)

Answer (score 0):

Esto tiene mas relación con la configuración de tu servidor que con el sistema de migraciones de Laravel.

Existe una variable de sistema llamada: `FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS` la cual es de carácter `boolean`.

Entonces si tu gestor esta permitiendo que ingreses registros con una llave foránea no existente es por que esta configurada con un valor de `0`; deberás ejecutar el siguiente comando en tu consola de *MySQL* para pasarlo a `1` y que se active.

```
SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS = 1;
```

Una vez hecho lo anterior, si tratas de insertar nuevamente esa llave foránea que no existe te devolverá un error como este:

> ERROR 1452 (23000): Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key
>   constraint fails (`ejemp lo`.`razas`, CONSTRAINT
>   `razas_mundo_id_foreign` FOREIGN KEY (`mundo_id`) REFERENCES `mundos`
>   (`id`))

Lo cual indica que ya esta funcionando dicha validación

**Referencias**

- [`foreign_key_checks`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_foreign_key_checks)